# prove or give counterexample about regular language

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

Let $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, $L_1,L_2\subseteq \Sigma^*$

$L_1 ◃ L_2 = \{w∈ \Sigma^* | \exists v\in L_1, vw \in L_2\}$

For any context-free language $L$, regular language $R$, whether  $L \triangleleft R$ is regular language or not? How to prove or give a counterexample?

Comment: Your operation is known as [left quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language).

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4431052) for a very similar question.

Answer (score 1):

After some google && watching some videos[1], I think I understand this:

consider there is a $R$ as regular language. We can get its DFA=$\{Q,\Sigma, \delta, q_0, F\}$, then we find all the status $q_i$ which $q_0$ to $q_i$ is in $L$, take these $q_i$ as begin. So we get a new (NFA), DFA. Which is to say, we get a regular language.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgUB_07N0eA